# Is there a more efficient LINQ statement to reverse-search for a condition in a List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, list

We're trying to write a LINQ statement against a `List<T>` that searches backwards from the end of that list for a condition, but which stops at a specified 'T' item.

For instance, if the list has 1000 items and the 'limit' item is at position 995 (index 994), then we only want to search the last six items for the test condition. We need this to be as high-performance as possible.

However, to use LINQ, the only way we know is to get the existing index of the 'limit' item, which is expensive, then run a Select with index over the entire source collection, which also is expensive, like this...

```
// Assume limitItem is of type Foo and sourceList is of type List<Foo> 

var limitIndex = sourceList.IndexOf(limitItem);
var sourceListWithIndex = sourceList.Select( (Foo, Index) => new { Foo, Index } );

var fooWithIndex = sourceListWithIndex
    .LastOrDefault(item =>
        (item.Foo.SomTestValue == true)
        &&
        (item.Index >= limitIndex) );
```

So is there an easier way to tell Linq 'Stop enumerating if you've checked this item', or will I have to manually do it myself in an index-based loop and not use LINQ at all?

Comment: suggest that you post a full example that is representative of what you're doing so we can see a bit more; I like @Slaks example; but as with anything performance related the only true test would be to profile it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any of that.

```
sourceList.Reverse()
          .TakeWhile(o => o != limitItem)
          .FirstOrDefault(o => ...);
```

Thanks to deferred execution (and assuming `sourceList` implements `IList<T>`), this will iterate part of the list exactly once.

Comment: Isn't that 'Reverse' call expensive in its own right? Also, we want our 'limit' item to be included in the check.  Doesn't this exclude it?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but can you somewhere in that set a flag saying 'limitItem was found' and use *that* along with the check against 'o' like this... 'o => o != limitItem && !limitItemFound'?  Not sure if you can set 'if(o == limitItem) limitItemFound' within a Linq statement.

Comment: FYI, I've now added this question in regards to your answer to see if I can make your solution inclusive of limitItem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164635  Feel free to answer that question there.

Comment: ...and as Jon Skeet pointed out, of course you can do what I've asked.  You just use the braces-version of the delegate where you can use multiple statements before the return.  Gotta be careful doing that though for the reasons in the comments to the question.

Comment: Shouldn't `.Reverse()` be `.Reverse<T>()` because `.Reverse()` of `List` returns void, while `IList` doesn't have `.Reverse()`?

Comment: I think `Reverse<T>()` may be implied here thanks to the typing.  It's the same reason when you call `.ToList()` at the end of an enumerable for a specific type you get a list of that specific type.  In general, generic signature matches are more granular than the non-generic versions so they match up first when being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the .NET source codes, and looks like `.Reverse` calls `.ToArray` internally, which iterates the whole collection. This kills all the performance benefits. https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Reverse.cs,57

So if you already know that the item is somewhere "closer to the end" - use `.LastOrDefault` which is optimized for `IList` internally (it takes the `IList.Count` and moves backwards from it.