# Can you set/update a value in real-time within a LINQ statement during iteration?

Tags: c#, linq

Based on a proposed answer to my other question [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164310) is it possible to update a variable during LINQ enumeration so you can use it as part of a test?

For instance, is anything like this possible?

```
// Assume limitItem is of type Foo and sourceList is of type List<Foo> 

// Note the faux attempt to set limitItemFound in the TakeWhile clause
// That is what I'm wondering.

sourceList.Reverse()
    .TakeWhile(o => (o != limitItem) && !limitItemFound; limitItemFound = limitItemFound || (o == limitItem) )
    .FirstOrDefault(o => ...);
```

This would make the search inclusive of limitItem.

Comment: I believe this is *possible* but you really have to be careful it's only evaluated once, when you expect, and in the order you expect.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? (And also, I updated the q.  There was a logic flaw.)

Comment: In your case you're ok since you're just returning FirstOrDefault, but if you were to keep it as IEnumerable and iterate twice, depending on the underlying implementation it may actually evaluate your TakeWhile twice, leaving residual values for your variables the second time around. (I think)

Comment: Very good point!  Deferred execution or restarts could be problematic.  +1!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For LINQ to Objects (which takes *delegates*) then you can, yes - using a *statement lambda*:

```
sourceList.Reverse()
    .TakeWhile(o =>  { 
             ... fairly arbitrary code here
             return someValue;
         })
    .FirstOrDefault(o => ...);
```

I would *strongly* discourage you from doing this though. It will make it *much* harder to understand what's going on, because you're losing the declarative nature of idiomatic LINQ code.

Comment: DUH! {{head-slap}}  Of course this is right!  I keep forgetting the delegate version has the braces-included syntax where you can do whatever you want.  Thanks! (BTW, I agree about clarity, but with a simple comment, it will be much clearer.)